# AutoHotkey: Bind one key to two modifier keys

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, autohotkey

My issue is deceivingly simple.

I have this combination in my .ahk file:

```
Capslock::Shift
```

This works. If I hold down <kbd>Capslock</kbd>, it doesn't activate, but it does whatever <kbd>Shift</kbd> has to do, which is exactly what I want.

Now, if I take it a step further:

```
Capslock::^+
```

It should work in paper, but it sends automatically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, instead of letting me use <kbd>Capslock</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Any thoughts on how to bind two modifier keys into one single key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify both the up and down actions. I also added the wildcard `*` option in case you wished to hold down another modifier key in addition to <kbd>Capslock</kbd>.

```
*Capslock::Send {Shift Down}{Control Down}
*Capslock Up::Send {Shift Up}{Control Up}
```

Comment: This is incredible, it worked! I completely misunderstand the usage of *Send* in the documentation examples, but this is crystal clear. Much obliged!